# microtype - pdftex 1.40 required - but installed

Tags: pdftex, luatex, microtype

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\begin{document}
Problems with LuaLaTeX hyphen mechanism 
\subsubsection{KI vom 25.9.2017: Aktualisierung der Sicherheitslage in Afghanistan – Q3.2017
(betrifft: Abschnitt 3 Sicherheitslage)}
Auch wenn Ghor als eine der unterentwickelten Provinzen Afghanistans angesehen
wird (IWPR 19.1.2017; vgl. auch: Pajhwok o.D.p), haben 6.131 Frauen einen
neun-monatigen 
\end{document}
```

When I compile the file with `lualatex` I get

```
! Package microtype Error: The spacing feature only works with pdftex 1.40
(microtype)                or newer. Switching it off.
```

But I have

```
> lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
> pdftex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
```

To my knowledge I should have pdfTex 1.40.18 Therefore I do not understand the error message. According to the manual it should works as well. Any idea what the error message points to?

Comment: you _have_ pdftex but you are using luatex, the message is telling you that that feature requires pdftex.

Comment: Meaning that this feature does not work when I compile with lualatex but with pdftex it should work? ahhh - thx for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pdftex but you are using luatex, the message is telling you that that feature requires pdftex.

Comment: What if want to use Lualatex? Is there an alternative?